# Anexar dos ceros despues del punto flotante pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Hoy desperte con una duda y despues de investigar y leer la documentacion no he podido resolver.
Supongamos que tenemos un *dataframe* de tipo ***float64*** como el siguiente:

```
     A     B    C     D
0  12.0  15.0  0.0   3.0
1   3.0   7.0  9.0  19.0
2  18.0   4.0  6.0  12.0
```

¿Como puedo visualizar el dataframe anterior con dos cifras significaticas sin importar que sean "00" esto sin hacer que las columnas sean de tipo ***object***? algo asi:

```
      A     B     C     D
0  12.00   15.00 0.00   3.00
1   3.00   7.00  9.00  19.00
2  18.00   4.00  6.00  12.00
```

Codigo utilizado hasta el momento:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cols = 4
rows = 3
np.random.seed(0)

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (rows, cols)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df= df.astype(float)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes Agregar la siguiente línea de código (preferiblemente después de la importación de los modulos, solo para que el código se vea en orden):

```py
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format
```

Esto hará que todos los tipos *float64* se muestren con dos decimales sin afectar el tipo de dato.

Por lo que tu código completo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2f}".format

cols = 4
rows = 3
np.random.seed(0)

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (rows, cols)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df= df.astype(float)
print(df)
#Muestra los tipos de datos para comprobar que siguen siendo de tipo float64
print(df.dtypes)
```

---

```
      A     B    C     D
0 12.00 15.00 0.00  3.00
1  3.00  7.00 9.00 19.00
2 18.00  4.00 6.00 12.00

A    float64
B    float64
C    float64
D    float64
dtype: object
```

### Nota:

Puede consultar mas acerca del tema en la documentacion > opciones y configuraciones [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, investigaré que más puedo hacer con _options.display_